# IOS ObjectiveC: How to change from String to Date, if we have TImeZone: Date is coming nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

Actually, I would like to change below string to date, When I'm trying to do this, I'm getting nil date.

Example 1: 
Input:
Tue 20 May 2014 09:30:00 PM IST

Looking for/Output : 09 PM (Only Time and AM/PM)

Example 2:
"Tue 20 May 2014 10:00:00 AM CDT"
Output : 10 AM

```
  NSString *dateString=@"20 May 2014 09:30:00 PM IST";
  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  formatter.dateFormat = @"EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss a zzzz";
  NSDate *time= [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
  //above time object is getting nil
```

Anybody can you please help me how to change above string to date/time format. I tried many ways But I'm getting nil date object when i'm trying to convert string to date.

Comment: Update your question with the code giving you the problem.

Comment: Are you using a date formatter?

Comment: Yes, I'm using DateFormatter, since we have time zones like IST, CDT ..etc.. it's not able to convert i think.

Comment: For the date format characters see: [Unicode Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Use NSDateFormatter.  There are literally thousands of examples to look at.  The critical point often missed is that the date format string must (duh!) actually match the format of the date you're parsing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is at least the 3rd query about using NSDateFormatter today.

Comment: No, Actually this is different requirement than the others. Tried many ways ... it's not generating date object;

Comment: Do you really think that your date format matches the format of the date string? It needs to match.

Comment: First, it's not converting as date object, once we have date object i can apply another formatter to get the exact output which i'm looking for. But, NSDate time object it's self i'm getting nil.

Comment: Stop down voting people and just look at this link to learn actually how to format date strings ::::::: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you are going to want to handle this:

```
        NSString * dateString = @"Tue 20 May 2014 10:00:00 AM IST";
        NSString *threeLetterZone = [[dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] lastObject];
        NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:threeLetterZone];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"EEE dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a z";
        NSDate *date;

        if (timeZone)
        {
            NSString *gmtTime = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:threeLetterZone withString:timeZone.abbreviation];
        date = [formatter dateFromString:gmtTime];
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

I know its a lot longer but this will return the GMT time of the string.

EDIT:

Cocoa is weird. You won't be able to preserve the timezone. Everything revolves around the GMT/UTC

If you want the local time:

```
        NSString * dateString = @"Tue 20 May 2014 10:00:00 AM IST";
        NSString *threeLetterZone = [[dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] lastObject];
        NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:threeLetterZone];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"EEE dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
        NSDate *date;

        if (timeZone)
        {
            NSString *gmtTime = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:threeLetterZone withString:@""];
        date = [formatter dateFromString:gmtTime];
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Comment: Your completely right. Its been a year or so since I've touched ObjC. Fixed!

Comment: yeah i got some idea now, Thank you so much. With the above code,  date object is showing in EDT time zone. Now totally it's showing different time that' is my local time zone EDT. Actually I want time 10 AM etc...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a subset of time zone abbreviations that work, mainly abbreviations that are tied to a country, not a region. Even timezone abbreviations such as CET (Central European Time) do not work but CST (Cuban Standard Time) does. This makes some sense since 12 vs 24 hour time is usually tied to a country, not a timezone.

There is another problem here, that is the use of English abbreviations: "Tue" and "May".

Here is a version based on the answer by @Chase Walden that does not use GMT. The key element is the same, getting the `NSTimeZone from the string. It is a bit longer.

```
NSString * dateString = @"Tue 20 May 2014 10:00:00 AM IST";

NSMutableArray *components = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
NSString *threeLetterZone = [components lastObject];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:threeLetterZone];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

if (timeZone) {
[components removeLastObject];
dateString = [components componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
    [formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
}
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

> 2014-05-20 04:30:00 +0000

Answer (score 0):

Here how you should do this in Objective C.
Igone the `setTimeZone` by the date formatter if you don't want any time zone changes.

```
NSString *inputDate = @"WhateverTheTime";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"CurrentDateTimeFormat"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"IST"]]; //Only if you want to change the timeZone
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:inputDate]; 

[formatter setDateFormat:@"RequiredDateTimeFormat"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]]; //Only if you want to change the timeZone
NSString *requiredOutput = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Cheers!!